# Getting a Character to freeze when their health reaches zero

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a car to just stop moving when its health reaches zero. I have tried using this method after finding it as a solution online, but it still doesn't seem to work. I also cant destroy the gameObject because other scripts are reliant on it being there.

```c#
public float health = 10;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "car")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Health: " + health);
        health--;

    }
    if (health <= 0) {

        gameObject.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: "I have tried using this method after finding it as a solution online, but it still doesn't seem to work":  What doesn't work?  Provide more detail as it doesn't work is hard to decipher

Comment: The example above is the one I tried to use.  with gameObject.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;                                                    It gives me an error reading that the unity engine component does not contain a definition for "velocity". I dont know of what else to use.

Comment: You should create a state of dead/frozen so in the OnCollision you put your car state to frozen.

Then in your update if the car is frozen do nothing

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, and I didn't post enough information. All I had to do was put the health code inside my player controller code and put an if statement around the entire player controller determining if the health was greater than zero. If anyone has a more efficient solution, please tell me.